# Compare values from sql to login successfully our windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

The following code inserts the values successfully to local db. I cannot retrieve them and compare them login to  next page

```
       public class Mytable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }


    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<Mytable>();

    }



    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        Mytable m = new Mytable();

        m.Name = text_reg.Text;
        m.Password = text_password.Password;
        string rd = "";
        if(radio_male.IsChecked==true)
        {
            rd = "Male";

        }
        else
        {
            rd = "Female";

        }
        m.Gender = rd;
        m.State = ((ComboBoxItem)combo_box.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();


        await con.InsertAsync(m);

        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("success");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/Mydb1.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);


        List<Mytable> mylist= await con.QueryAsync<Mytable>("select * from Mytable where Name='" + text_reg.Text + "' and Password='" + text_password.Password + "'");
        foreach(Mytable r in mylist)
        {


                if (r.Name == text_reg.Text && r.Password == text_password.Password)
                {
                    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Blankpage1));
                }
                else
                {
                    var messagedialog = new MessageDialog("Unsuccessful").ShowAsync();
                }

        }


    }
```

I cannot compare and retrieve the inserted values. Please help me to make my login successful

Comment: the codes seems OK, before querying with username and password. query all the table records and see if it has records saved.

Comment: try to use just *Mydb1.db* as the database path.